# Simple functionnal way for grouping successive elements?

Tags: scala

Let's take the string "AAAABCCCBBBBBBAAACC" : I would like to build a kind of Iterable such as this Vector [('A', 4), ('B',1), ('C', 3), ('B', 6), ('A',3), ('C', 2)] (which list letters occurences in order). What is the simplest functionnal approch for doing that in Scala ?

All I've found is to use a for clause (or a foreach call) and to rely upon some vars : nothing better. Is there a single method that I can call on my collection (or a method chain) ?

Indeed, after having written several codes, it seems that doing this is a recurring pattern to me.

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement or do you just want a working function?  Because Scala has a groupBy method

Comment: GroupBy seems good to me : how can I use this function with the string I gave above ? (It seems it take a single argument)

Comment: `groupBy` will group also non consecutive letters, eg in your case `A` will have 7 as value and not 4.

Comment: Yes it fit to my needs : that's a duplicate. Apologizing